# Display label and shape at the same time

Tags: java, awt

We just started with GUI Programming in Java using AWT only. My task is to draw an ellipse and display it together with a label. Somehow I can't figure out how to display them at the same time. As soon as I add

```
add(label);
```

to my program it only displays the label.
Thats my code so far...

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Ellipse extends Frame{

public static void main (String args[]) {
    new Ellipse("Ellipse");
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    Graphics shape = g.create();
    shape.setColor(Color.black);
    shape.fillRect(100,80,100,40);
    shape.setColor(Color.red);
    shape.fillOval(100,80,100,40);

} 

Ellipse(String s){
        super(s);
        setLocation(40,40);
        setSize(300,300);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        Font serif = new Font("Serif", 1, 10);
        setFont(serif);
        Label label = new Label("Ellipse 1",1);
        add(label);
        setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The actual task is to draw an ellipse, fill the background with black and put a label below. Besides my problem, is there a possibility to fill the background of the oval with color other than drawing a seperate rectangle first?

Comment: Instead of using paint, you should use paintComponent. Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all when you override a method you should call parents method call cause u can break liskov substitution principle.

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics shape = g.create();
        shape.setColor(Color.black);
        shape.fillRect(100,80,100,40);
        shape.setColor(Color.red);
        shape.fillOval(100,80,100,40);
        shape.dispose();// And if you create it, you should dispose it   
    }
```

And the ellipse is not showing cause you never set a Layout, in your constructor you have to put something like this

```
    Ellipse(String s){
        super(s);
        setLocation(40,40);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(300,300);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        Font serif = new Font("Serif", 1, 10);
        setFont(serif);
        Label label = new Label("Ellipse 1",1);
        add(label);
        pack(); // size the frame
        setVisible(true);
}
```

And the result

[image: frame result]

**NOTE** You should not paint in top level containers , it is a good practice you to add your components for example in a `Panel` and override the paint method in the panel.

Comment: And if you create it, you should dispose it (ie the Graphics)

Comment: Suggest using paintComponent over paint (as per my comment to the question) and you're on your way to a winning question ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer but that is for swing components or it's also for awt? cause he is using all awt

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed he was overriding `Frame`, then the OP should avoid overriding `paint` on top level containers :P

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any AWT only Tutorial you can suggest? Most ones I found so far also use swing...